# rvm get latest ERROR

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-lion

Just upgraded to Lion and tried to update `rvm` [following the doc](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/upgrading/):

```
$ rvm get latest

Original installed RVM version:

rvm 1.2.8 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

rvm-<html>
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   172    0   172    0     0    210      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   304
ERROR:
.tar.gz downloaded does not match it's md5 checksum <html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.0.8</center>
</body>
./html>
    Aborting RVM Installation.
```

How can I upgrade `rvm` on Lion?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly it might just be easier to `rvm implode` and start over. You're pretty dang far behind on versions. So it might not be able to jump that far in versions from an update.

My current version is `1.8.6`.

Run `rvm implode`, this will remove rvm, rubies, gemsets, everything.

Run

```
bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

Thats my solution...

Comment: Some of the rvm versions cannot be upgraded to others.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, if rvm get latest is not working and imploding your installation is not an option, then you can always do:

```
rvm get head
```

This gets the latest version from Git, so it circumvents the Bad Request error. After that you can do a

```
rvm get latest
```

to switch to the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

WAY too old to properly upgrade. The suggestion to implode is exactly what to do. Please see my script at the bottom of the Troubleshooting page for a script that will remove any and all traces of RVM from your system. Comment out any lines in your $HOME/.bashrc|.bash_profile that load RVM. Then immediately log out then back in so there are absolutely no variables for RVM in the environment and then follow through the install procedure as detailed on the rvm installation page.

PLEASE NOTE: Do NOT use Xcode 4.2. It currently does not properly build a lot of different rubies and native-extension gems, as well as Homebrew and MacPorts builds. Use only Xcode 4.1 plus any updates Apple has supplied.

This is not a RVM issue, its a compiler issue due to the changeover to LLVM.